# Web pages running on XAMPP server loading very slowly

Tags: php, windows, server, xampp

I had a MySQL database running on XAMPP and it has user-friendly web pages developed using Laravel. XAMPP had been running on Windows 10 recently and it was doing well. I installed XAMPP on a Windows Seever 2016 OS and exported the database and pages to this server. Now, pages are loaded extremely slowly. The server is on a virtual machine and has 32 GB Ram and a decent Processor. What would be the issue?

Comment: Hi Rafiq, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you define 'extremely slowly'? Are we talking a couple of seconds or 10's? If you look at the activity monitor can you see what impact the site has on the CPU or memory? Does it spike?

Comment: It delays 7-12 seconds to load a page. The apache service uses only 1 percent of the CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. There was a js file that need to be loaded from internet so that it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue where it can relate to DNS or IPv6 resolution.

So I would look at ruling out IPv6 issues first.

Ideally, you would prefer IPv4 over ipv6 but just to test the theory, try disabling it first and see if it makes a difference.

- Open up `regedit`
- Find `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters\`
- Edit `DisabledComponents`
- Set the value to `0xFF` (to disable it)

You might need to restart to see if this makes a difference.

If it does, repeat the above steps and change the value to `0x20` (Prefer IPv4 over IPv6)

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows

Comment: Hi there!

Thanks for your comment.

I did but that did not help, unfortunately.